# Inner Join with two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, inner-join

I want to make a selection that look up values of ID to Username from two columns in the same table:

Table: `Gift`

```
FromID ToID
1      2
2      6
3      2
5      3
```

TableL `Users`

```
UserID   Username
1        A
2        B
3        C
4        D
5        E
6        F
```

Expected Output:

```
FromUser   ToUser
A          B
B          F
C          B
E          C
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one trick using `JOIN` with `IN` condition

```
SELECT Max(CASE WHEN FromID = u.UserID THEN Username END),
       Max(CASE WHEN ToID = u.UserID THEN Username END)
FROM   users u
       JOIN gift g
         ON u.UserID IN ( g.FromID, g.ToID )
GROUP  BY FromID,
          ToID
```

Or you need to join the `users` table twice

```
SELECT f.Username,
       t.Username
FROM   gift g
       LEFT JOIN users f
              ON f.UserID = g.FromID
       LEFT JOIN users t
              ON t.UserID = g.ToID
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a recap on how to work with several relationships between the same two tables.

Your gift table has a relationship that describes who gave the gift - I call it giver here; and a relationship that described who received the gift - I call it receiver here. Both relationships from gift are many-to-one towards the users table.

You simply join the same table twice and give that table a good correlation name - giver and receiver in my example - to show in the code what you're using them for.

Like so:

```
 WITH
gift(fromid,toid) AS (
          SELECT 1,2
UNION ALL SELECT 2,6
UNION ALL SELECT 3,2
UNION ALL SELECT 5,3
)
,
users(userid,username) AS (
          SELECT 1,'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'B'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'C'
UNION ALL SELECT 4,'D'
UNION ALL SELECT 5,'E'
UNION ALL SELECT 6,'F'
)
SELECT
  giver.username    as fromUser
, receiver.username as toUser
FROM gift
JOIN users AS giver
  ON gift.fromid=giver.userid
JOIN users AS receiver
  ON gift.toid  =receiver.userid
ORDER BY 1,2
;

fromUser|toUser
A       |B
B       |F
C       |B
E       |C
```